# How to install/deploy VSTO Excel 2010 Addin developed in C#.net?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have developed an excel addin using VSTO in C#.net .Now i want to deploy this addin in other machines too .So that users who installed this can see my addin in excel menu -> Addins-> MyAddin

Alternatively can i give them just Excel with myaddin.So that whoever has this Excel can access addin and use it.This way they don't see myaddin in every excel file addins menu.

Comment: Have you checked the VSTO page? It has a whole set of explanations and instructions on how to deploy a VSTO add-in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/office/hh128824

Comment: Haha, I love how everyone's like oooh, answer, check this link... Thanx for the help guys....

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Visual Studio 2010 setup project to create a Windows Installer package. See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) Link

Quote from that Link

> Summary: Learn how to deploy a Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for the
>   Office system 2010 add-in or document- level solution using a Visual
>   Studio 2010 setup project to create a Windows Installer package that
>   targets the 2007 Microsoft Office system or Microsoft Office 2010.
>
> Wouter van Vugt, Code Counsel
>
> Ted Pattison, Ted Pattison Group
>
> This article was updated by Microsoft with permission from the
>   original authors.
>
> Applies to: Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office, 2007 Microsoft Office
>   system, Microsoft Office 2010, Visual Studio 2010.
>
> Download: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSTO2010MSI
>
> Contents
>
> ```
> Overview
> Deployment Methods
> Deploying Office solutions that target the Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office runtime
> Download Samples Provided with this Article
> Creating a Basic Installer
> Conclusion
> Additional Resources
> About the Authors
> ```

**EDIT**

You may also see this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx) for All Users.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, all you need to concentrate on is get yourself a COM object created which must be running even when the application (MS Excel here) is not open in the explorer.

More can be figured out from the following link :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7859/Building-COM-Objects-in-C

(P.S : link is for c# not c).

Next you should give your users a .exe file including code to create the COM object.