# Install plugin when outlook loads

Tags: plugins, outlook, installation, vsto

So , I've made an setup and after running it , it creates me a folder where my VSTO plugin is in . Then I need to run the VSTO file manually for my plugin to be loaded in outlook . I want that , after running the setup, when the user opens Outlook , the vsto installer to pop up  . How can I make that?

Comment: Do you require to register the plugin for each individual user or would installing the plugin for all users (i.e. LOCALMACHINE) be an option?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026176/how-to-install-deploy-vsto-excel-2010-addin-developed-in-c-net

Comment: this is not what I asked . I don't think it's the same question

Comment: You may want to consider [some reasons to not install your plugin that way](http://devnet.superoffice.com/Technical/Forum/Rooms/Topic/superoffice-product-group/crm-windows-application/why-we-should-not-run-vsto-installer-manually/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your user being prompted to install the Outlook Addin on (first) Application startup you can distribute the according registry key by means of a Group Policy.

The key and its values should look like this:

```
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\YOUR_ADDIN_NAME]
 @=""
 "Manifest"="file:///C:\FULL\PATH\TO\YOUR_ADDIN_NAME.vsto"
 "LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
 "FriendlyName"="YOUR_ADDIN_NAME"
 "Description"="Your Addin description here."
```

However this can result in your users being prompted to re-install the Addin every time Outlook is started because the according registry key is not persisted due to security permissions.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I want